# Java web application form validation implimentation

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have to add an additional validation rule to a form field in a Java web application.
I have a rule in place that validates that the form field value entered is that of a valid employee ID.

But now I would like to verify that this value is either the Employee ID of the form/web user or of an employee of the form/web user. In other words an employee can enter an event against their own employee ID and a supervisor can enter an event against their own employee ID as well as an ID of an employee they supervise badge.  Here is what I have.

```
public Object insert(HttpServletRequest request) {
    OopEvent event = new OopEvent();
    STKUser authenticatedUser = (STKUser) request.getSession().getAttribute("STKUserSession");

    try {
        // populate bean with setters
        processEventBadge (request, event);
        processEventEventTypeID(request, event);
        processEventStartDate (request, event);
        processEventEndDate (request, event);
        processEventHours (request, event);
        if (isSucces()) {
            EventDAO.insert(event, authenticatedUser);
        }
        else {
            setError(FORM_RESULTS, "Error - There are error(s) in your input. See below.");
            LOGGERI.log(Level.INFO, "Form input errors inserting OopEvent", authenticatedUser);
        }
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        setError(FORM_RESULTS, e.getMessage());
    }
    return event;
}


// Field processors
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void processEventBadge(HttpServletRequest request, OopEvent event) throws DAOException {
    String _badge = FormUtil.getFieldValue(request, FIELD_BADGE);
    if (!"".equals(_badge) && _badge != null) {
        try {
            event.setBadge(_badge);
            event.setEventUser(STKUserDAO.getValidEmployeeByBadge(_badge)); //Returns user bean
//should make a call to validate event employee ID HERE?????????? If so I need the send eventUser and authenticatedUser but authenticatedUser is not available here only the eventUser (only if the badge number is of a valid employee)
        }
        catch (ValidatorException e) {
            setError(FIELD_BADGE, e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (DAOException e) {
            setError(FIELD_BADGE, e.getMessage());
            throw new DAOException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    else {
         setError(FIELD_BADGE, "OopEvent Owner badge is required");
    }
}
```

Should I implement this logic in the `insert` method, the `processEventBadge` or in a `validateEventBadge` method??  Or somewhere else?? I think I should put a call in the `processEventBadge` to a `validateEventBadge` method but that would require me to pass the authenticatedUser object to both methods.  A User Object contains an employee ID and the supervisors employee ID.  So I could make sure the logged in user supervisors the event by comparing the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

The last thing you mentioned sounds good.

I would also put a call in the processEventBadge to a validateEventBadge method.

The passing of the user object is an easy thing.